# Wordpress in waiting state

Tags: redirect, wordpress

I built a website for someone and I used https://gtmetrix.com to get some analytics, mainly because the wait time is huge (~20 sec) without having any heavy images. Please find attached a screenshot here:
http://img42.com/05yvZ

One of my problems is that it takes quite a long time to perform the 301 redirect. Not sure why, but if someone has a key to the solution I would really appreciate. At least some hints to search would be nice.

The second problem is after the redirection, the waiting time is still huge. As expected I have a few plugins. Their javascripts are called approx. 6 secs after the redirection. Would someone please show me some directions on where to search please?

P.S. I have disabled all plugins and started from a naked plain Twenty Eleven theme, but I still have waiting times during redirection and smaller delay after redirection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I've ran the test, it does indicate a waiting state, but I can't see at which part is waiting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**But a few suggestions:**

**1 and 2.)** If **the redirect** is adding noticeable delays; test different redirect methods. There are several approaches to this -- including HTML meta and server side (ie PHP) methods -- I typically stick to server side; if it's showing noticeable delays using a server side method, this may be a great indicator that your experiencing ***server issues*** - and may be very well your server all along causing your speed issues; contact your host provider.

**3.)** Take a look at the **size of your media**. Images and Video; also Flash if your using any. Often cases it's giant images that were just sliced / saved poorly and not optimized for web in a image editing software like PhotoShop. Optimize your images for web and re-save them at a lower weight to save significant on load time. Also, many cases nowadays and you can avoid using clunky images in general by building the area out using pure CSS3. *(ie. Odd repeatable `.gifs` to create gradients or borders etc.)*

Comment: thanks, I've updated the original post with the link, however I don't have enough credits to post a second link...

Comment: I suspect it may be your server - if my other two points above don't ring any bells. Most cases you can just call them; maybe your using an outdated php version or something.

Comment: ok thank you for your feedback. it will be on my TODO list for tomorrow :). Thumbs up from me for helping me ..

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful!

Comment: cant vote up coz i have 13 points. maybe you can vote me up to give me a few credits and then I will be able to vote for you